# How to display list of json data using bullet in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to displaly if the answer is obj it shoud be display as paragraph and if it is array it should be display the list using bullets or numbered. eg,
 1. i like maths,
 2. it is not difficult

my controller is,

```
    $scope.books = {
        "types": [
            {
                "category": "subjects",
                "sub": [
                    {
                        "question": "what is maths",
                        "answer": {
                           "obj": "it is a subject",
                           "array": [
                                "i like maths",
                                "it is not difficult"
                            ],
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "what is science  ?",
                        "answer": {
                           "obj": "it is a subject",
                           "array": [
                                "i like maths",
                                "it is not difficult"
                            ],
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

My htlm code is,

```
     <div ng-repeat="book in books.types">
     <div ng-repeat="ans in sub.answer"> 
        {{ans}}
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: you can use `<ol>` tag for numbers simple .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.books = {
        "types": [
            {
                "category": "subjects",
                "sub": [
                    {
                        "question": "what is maths",
                        "answer": {
                           "obj": "it is a subject",
                           "array": [
                                "i like maths",
                                "it is not difficult"
                            ],
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "what is science  ?",
                        "answer": {
                           "obj": "it is a subject",
                           "array": [
                                "i like maths",
                                "it is not difficult"
                            ],
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="book in books.types">
     <div ng-repeat="ans in book.sub"> 
            <p>  {{ans.answer.obj}} </p>
            <ul><li ng-repeat="testans in ans.answer.array">  {{testans}} </li><ul>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah... It is working... thank you so much.. but the obj is displaying as list. it should be normal paragraph.....

Comment: then use <p> tag

Comment: i want ot add question for each subject.. In this case what i have to do..

Comment: <div ng-repeat="book in books.types">
     <div ng-repeat="ans in sub.answer"> 
        {{ans}}
      </div>
     </div>

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work as per your expectation :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.books = {
        "types": [
            {
                "category": "subjects",
                "sub": [
                    {
                        "question": "what is maths ?",
                        "answer": {
                           "obj": "it is a subject",
                           "array": [
                                "i like maths",
                                "it is not difficult"
                            ],
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "question": "what is science  ?",
                        "answer": {
                           "obj": "it is a subject",
                           "array": [
                                "i like maths",
                                "it is not difficult"
                            ],
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
});
```

```css
.answer-heading {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="book in books.types">
     <div ng-repeat="item in book.sub">
        <h2>Question : <span>{{item.question}}</span></h2>
        <p><span class="answer-heading">Answer : </span>{{item.answer.obj}}</p>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="elem in item.answer.array">{{elem}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Rohit Jindal

Comment: Can you add the condition for how to check whether the answer is array or object.. according to the condition it should display the answer